# Having to use mvn clean compile every time

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I'm using spring boot with mapstruct, every time i restart my computer, when i try to start my application i get this error:

```
Description:

Field personMapper in com.paulo.enterprise.credito.services.PersonServices required a bean of type 'com.paulo.enterprise.credito.mapper.PersonMapper' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.paulo.enterprise.credito.mapper.PersonMapper' in your configuration.
```

The only way that I can fix the error is running mvn clean compile in the terminal, after that I can stop and start the application as many times as i want and the error will not show again, after i turn my computer off and turn it on again and try to run my application, the error returns and i need to run the mvn clean compile again. The problem lies in the mapstruct package but I don't know how to fix it.(I'm using postgresql as my db with Docker and I'm using eclipse IDE)

My Person(it has getters, setters, hashcode and equals):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String address;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 6)
    private String gender;
```

My PersonDTO(it has getters, setters, hashcode and equals):

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "gender", "firstName", "lastName", "address" })
public class PersonDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String address;

    private String gender;

    public PersonDTO() {}
```

My PersonMapper:

```
package com.paulo.enterprise.credito.mapper;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PersonMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "firstName", source = "person.firstName")
    PersonDTO personToPersonDTO(Person person);

    List<PersonDTO> personListToPersonDTOList(List<Person> persons);

    Person personDTOToPerson(PersonDTO personDTO);
}
```

My PersonService(it has the all crud methods):

```
@Service
public class PersonServices {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PersonServices.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private PersonMapper personMapper;

    @Autowired
    private PersonMapperV2 personMapperV2;

    public List<PersonDTO> findAll() {
        logger.info("Finding all persons");

        return personMapper.personListToPersonDTOList(repository.findAll());
    }

    public PersonDTO findById(Long id) {
        logger.info("Finding one person");
        Person person = repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("No records found for this id"));
        return personMapper.personToPersonDTO(person);
    }

    public PersonDTO create(PersonDTO person) {
        logger.info("Creating one person");
        Person personEntity = personMapper.personDTOToPerson(person);
        Person savedPerson = repository.save(personEntity);
        return personMapper.personToPersonDTO(savedPerson);
    }
```

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.paulo.enterprise.credito</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-0.1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myapp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
          <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.5.Final</version> 
    </dependency>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your pom.xml it looks like you haven't configured Eclipse to properly configure your project.

You need to make sure that you have the [m2e-apt](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/m2e-apt) plugin installed (if you are using Eclipse 2022.9 or later it is automatically there).

You should make sure that you have the following in your properties

```
<!-- automatically run annotation processors within the incremental compilation -->
  <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
```

This is also explained in the [Eclipse IDE setup](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/#eclipse) section on the MapStruct website

Comment: thank you for your answer @Filip, it seems that it solved the problem that I was having, now once i open the project I do not need to run the mvn clean compile, but when I add a new dependency in my pom.xml I still need to run mvn clean compile, is this normal?

Comment: That to me looks like Eclipse isn't picking up your maven configuration properly. I am not an Eclipse user, so can't say exactly how to configure that

Comment: I've been having some problems with Eclipse lately, I'll problably change to some other IDE. Thank for your help @Filip